# Split list and create a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings like this:

```
lis_val = ['Mon 01/12/2020 apple', 'Tue 01/13/2020 orange', 'Wed 01/14/2020 peach']
```

I need to assemble a dataframe from this list as:

```
df = Mon  01/12/2020 apple
     Tue  01/13/2020 orange
     Wed  01/14/2020 peach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [82]: lis_val = ['Mon 01/12/2020 apple', 'Tue 01/13/2020 orange', 'Wed 01/14/2020 peach']
    ...:

In [83]: pd.DataFrame([i.split() for i in lis_val])
Out[83]:
     0           1       2
0  Mon  01/12/2020   apple
1  Tue  01/13/2020  orange
2  Wed  01/14/2020   peach
```

Comment: How to get result in wide format such as instead of three columns I have nine such as: day_1 date_1 fruuit_1 day_2 date_2 fruit_2 day_3 date_3 fruit_3

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pd.Series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`:

```
import pandas as pd

lis_val = ['Mon 01/12/2020 apple', 'Tue 01/13/2020 orange', 'Wed 01/14/2020 peach']
df=pd.DataFrame(lis_val)[0].str.split(expand=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     0           1       2
0  Mon  01/12/2020   apple
1  Tue  01/13/2020  orange
2  Wed  01/14/2020   peach
```